# How to allow empty value for Laravel numeric validation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How to set not require numeric validation for Laravel5.2? I just used this Code but when i don't send value or select box haven't selected item I have error the val field most be numeric... I need if request hasn't bed input leave bed alone. leave bed validate ...

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'provinces_id' => 'required|numeric',
        'type' => 'required',
        'bed' => 'numeric',
]);
```

Comment: you should make it nullable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you're looking for [`sometimes`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#conditionally-adding-rules) rule:

```
'bed' => 'sometimes|numeric',
```

> In some situations, you may wish to run validation checks against a field only if that field is present in the input array. To quickly accomplish this, add the `sometimes` rule to your rule list

Answer (score 4):

In Laravel 6 or 5.8, you should use **nullable**. But sometimes keyword doesn't work on that versions.

Answer (score 3):

Use `sometimes` instead of `required` in validation rules. It checks if only there is a value. Otherwise it treats parameter as optional.

Answer (score 3):

You may need **`nullable`** – `sometimes` and
`present` didn't work for me when combined with `integer|min:0` on a standard text input type - the integer error was always triggered.

> **[A Note on Optional Fields](https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/validation#a-note-on-optional-fields)**
>
> By default, Laravel includes the TrimStrings and ConvertEmptyStringsToNull middleware in your application's global middleware stack. These middleware are listed in the stack by the App\Http\Kernel class. Because of this, you will often need to mark your "optional" request fields as nullable if you do not want the validator to consider null values as invalid.

*Tested with Laravel 6.0-dev*

[Full list of available rules](https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/validation#available-validation-rules)

Answer (score 3):

In laravel 5.5 or versions after it, we begin to use **nullable** instead of **sometimes**.

Answer (score 1):

according to laravel documentation 8 you must to set nullable rule
for example:

```
 $validated = $request->validate([
            'firstName' => ['required','max:255'],
            'lastName' => ['required','max:255'],
            'branches' => ['required'],
            'services' => ['required' , 'json'],
            'contract' => ['required' , 'max:255'],
            'FixSalary' => ['nullable','numeric' , 'max:90000000'],
            'Percent' => ['nullable','numeric' , 'max:100'],
        ]);
```

in your case :

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'provinces_id' => 'required|numeric',
        'type' => 'required',
        'bed' => 'nullable|numeric',
]);
```